# Printer Toner leaking before and after cartridge replacement

Tags: printer, toner

Our HP CP4025 color printer was leaking magenta toner. We removed the cartridge, cleaned out the area, then replaced it with a brand new cartridge. It is now leaking again, leaving streaks on the paper (only when magenta is a color used) and toner leaked around the cartridge.

Is there any other part of the printer that could cause the cartridge to leak? It seems supremely unlikely that the brand new cartridge immediately leaked upon being placed in the printer.

If it is relevant, the new toner already shows supply levels being @ 90%.

Comment: The previous toner cartridge may have been misplaced into the printer, damaging the socket. Try to remove the toner and look for broked pieces of plastic.

Comment: I assume you have contacted HP?